# how do you sign and verify a message that you own a bitcoin address using javascript?

Tags: message-signing, javascript

Is there a bitcoin library or even just pure javascript way of **signing** and **verifying** you own a btc address?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[bitcoinjs-lib](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib) and [bitcore-lib](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-lib) are both javascript libraries that allow for key signing.

For example with bitcore-lib:

```
var Message = require('bitcore-message');

var privateKey = new bitcore.PrivateKey('L23PpjkBQqpAF4vbMHNfTZAb3KFPBSawQ7KinFTzz7dxq6TZX8UA');
var message = new Message('This is an example of a signed message.');

var signature = message.sign(privateKey);
```

EDIT: To also include the verification example from bitcore's github.

```
var Message = require('bitcore-message');

var address = '13Js7D3q4KvfSqgKN8LpNq57gcahrVc5JZ';
var signature = 'IBOvIfsAs/da1e36W8kw1cQOPqPVXCW5zJgNQ5kI8m57FycZXdeFmeyoIqJSREzE4W7vfDmdmPk0HokuJPvgPPE=';

var verified = new Message('This is an example of a signed message.').verify(address, signature);
```

Comment: how do you verify it?

Comment: https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-lib/blob/master/docs/examples.md#verify-a-bitcoin-message

Comment: Here's an example with BitcoinJS in the Blockchain.info wallet:
Sign: https://github.com/blockchain/My-Wallet-V3/blob/master/src/address.js#L260-L273 (ignore the code that refers to `secondPassword`)
Verify: https://github.com/blockchain/My-Wallet-V3/blob/v3.28.6/src/helpers.js#L441-L443

Comment: https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-message